# #61042 - An error occurred while processing the outgoing email message with subject "RE: test "

Tags: email, dynamics-crm

I have installed email router server on production server where Dynamics crm has been installed but when try to reply any mail, the result shows pending send and an error shows in event viewer. I am trying to send mail using a SMTP Relay server. Although, the same application with in same domain and same settings on testing server is working fine.

The event viewer error log is as given below.

Description:

> 61042 - An error occurred while processing the outgoing email message with subject "RE: test " for SMTP: http://172.26.4.123/TESTCRM for
>   delivery through 172.26.4.124.
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow.

Hope you are doing well. Let try some steps to troubleshooting the issue:

1. Set the E-mail Router Outgoing profile to Anonymous.

   a. Launch the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 E-mail Router.

   b. Open the Outgoing SMTP profile.

   c. In the Authentication Type drop down, choose Anonymous.

   d. Click Publish.
2. Updated the settings for the outgoing profile of the email router to use SSL and matched the name of the SMTP server with the name of the certificate. In this case, the proper name was the FQDN of the Exchange server.

** SSL for SMTP is not supported in Ex2010, so if this is your escenario then: unchecked “SSL” for SMTP, saved CRM router settings.

Please find below articles regarding your issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954584/error-message-when-you-try-to-test-access-from-the-microsoft-dynamics

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/99471

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/231301

[Dynamics CRM Email Router Troubleshooting 101 – Outgoing Emails](http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/09/19/dynamics-crm-email-router-troubleshooting-101-outgoing-emails/)